# Почему Telegram бот иногда долго отправляет инфу, иногда вообще не присылает, иногда задваивает сообщения?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, парсер, telegram, nginx

Пишу приложение tg-бота такого рода: сотрудники скидывают в чат вводные данные, бот их получает и на их основе парсит информацию в интернете. Отправляет ее ответом в чат.

**Проблема:** При парсинге из одного из источников бот долго висит при ответе. Иногда он ничего не отвечает на сообщение, иногда отвечает успешно, но с задваиванием, затраиванием и даже зачетверением информации. Если отвечает, то долго. Если не парсить источник, вызывающий проблемы, то все работает хорошо. Если запускать код источника, вызывающего проблемы, независимо от бота, то он отрабатывает (даже в тех случаях, когда в боте ничего не отдает, работает долго).

**Об источнике, вызывающем проблему:** паршу через курл с проксированием и использованием прокси сервера отсюда:

https://hidemy.io/ru/proxy-list/?start=12288#list

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //Автоматический редирект
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Отключение проверки сертификта
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

**Подробнее о боте:** бот выложен на обычном платном хостинге. Если после неудачных срабатываний бота смотреть логи сервера, то там нет ошибки. Работает через  на TG через вебхук. Закидывает сообщения так:

```
$urlQuery = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/sendMessage?chat_id=". $chat_id ."&text=" . $textMessage;

$result = file_get_contents($urlQuery);
```

В интернете советуют проверять, не запускается ли бот несколько раз в коде, в ответ на сообщение. Проверил - ничего подобного.

Опытные специалисты, подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать!

Сообщение из getWebhookInfo()

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пишите свои логи. на CURL ставьте таймаут. иногда запросы с прокси висят очень долго. процесс отваливается, а потом CURL возвращает чтото. у вас ведь обыгран сценарий если дохлый прокси или ответ пустой?

Comment: телега повторно может посылать хуку если предыдущий запрос завершился неудачно, то есть ваша обработка хуки упала. Если и все повторные упадут, то ничего к вам и не прийдет. Если в обработке хуки ходите в сторонние ресурсы через прокси, до убедитесь, что таймаут запроса приемлем. ТГ тоже там не будет ждать наверное 10 минут пока вы обрабатываете хуку. Мб прокси быть недоступны.

Comment: принятие хуки по хорошему должно быть мгновенное. Пришла хука - сложили в редис/раббит/БД или еще какое хранилище. Сделали воркер который с оттуда забирает, обрабатывает и отправляет клиентку ответ.

Comment: @sterx функция getWebhookInfo() вернула ошибку Read timeout expired попробовал в самый долгий curl запрос добавить timeout 20, 50 секунду - не повлияло на результат. а больше ставить вроде не рекоммендуется, как я вычитал.

Comment: @teran у меня сейчас так работает: Получаю сообщение пользователя в $tmpdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); потом работает парсер, собирающий данные, потом методом sendMessage и функцией file_get_contents все это дело отправляется ботом.. Вы имеете в виду. что нужно данные сначала собрать сложить в таблицу или Redis? Но я не знаю, какие данные искать, пока не разберу сообщение клиента из телеги. Поэтому сложить заранее результаты работы парсера нет возмонжости.. Или как-то можно положить хуку? А как? В документации ничего не нашел https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

Comment: @teran минут пять может все это висеть, не десять.. но пять может..

Comment: @teran хук прочитывает индексный файл (целиком или до отправки сообщения?), можно убрать оттуда тяжелые составляющие и тяжелые части обрабатывать с помощью getUpdates.

Comment: вы же с хуки через php://input получили данные сообщений. вот его и сохраните к себе. потом уже воркером обрабатывайте сохраненные. зы: обновленяи с телеги можно получить либо хуками либо через getUpdates, вместе эти методы не работают. В целом как вариант, можете работать через `getUpdates` целиком. Но учитывайте, что потенциально сообщения могут приходить чаще чем вы успеваете обрабатывать очередь, так что разбор обнов надо проводить в несколько потоков (если для вашего проекта такое актуально конечно).

Comment: @teran Я, в общем, так и делаю.. из input сообщение сохраняю в файл на сервере. Потом достаю, и обрабатываю. Из работы всех парсеров у меня формируется единая строка сообщения и я ее отправляю. Тем не менее, получаю эту ошибку с хуком. Кстати, у меня после разбора сообщения пользователя запускается несколько парсеров. Если убрать самый долгий, то бот благополучно шлет сообщение с ответом. А вот с включенными всеми парсерами не работает.. Может, слать несколькими сообщениями? Т.е. несколько раз делать sendMessange? Как вы думаете. может это помочь?

Comment: @teran getUpdate не хотелось бы.. хотелось бы, конечно, что то с WebHook сделать.. Я пробовал добавить параметр allowed_updates, чтобы он прямо ждал сообщения, но не помогло

Comment: @teran или можно как-то закрыть соединение, потом открыть непосредственно перед отправкой? В документации ничего не нашел.. может это из общей теории хуков, не знаете?